# Spark - Can't create schema for array of structs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a fairly simple schema for a dataframe that contains an array of structs, but I simply can't get it to work.  I've read several similar questions here on SO, but still not working.  I've been through several iterations.  Here's my current attempt:

```
val theSchema = StructType (
    StructField("dateTime",StringType,true),  
    StructField("sys",StringType,true),
    StructField("attribs",ArrayType(StructType(StructField("attribName",StringType,true), StructField("attribValue",StringType,true)),true),true)
)
```

That fails with this error:

```
<console>:29: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField)
           StructField("attribs",ArrayType(StructType(StructField("attribName",StringType,true), StructField("attribValue",StringType,true)),true),true)
                                           ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signature of [`StructType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):

```
StructType(fields: Array[StructField]) extends DataType with Seq[StructField] with Product with Serializable
```

it takes a collection of `StructField`s; and as noted in the API doc, one can construct a `StructType` object as `StructType(fields: Seq[StructField])`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val theSchema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("dateTime", StringType, true),  
  StructField("sys", StringType, true),
  StructField("attribs", ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
    StructField("attribName", StringType, true),
    StructField("attribValue", StringType, true)
  )), true), true)
))
```